# Is an arithmetic shift operator useful?

Tags: programming-languages, operators, language-design

Assume a language's division operator (`/`) rounds towards `-infinity`.

Other than potentially increased performance, is there any use in the language including an arithmetic shift operator (`>>`, say), given that `x >> y` would be equivalent to `x / (2 ** y)`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - it's useful to make it clear that you're interested in bitshifting operations; that you're thinking of a value as "a sequence of bits" rather than a magnitude.

For example, if I'm trying to represent a 32-bit integer in four bytes (and I don't have a simpler way of doing it) I might use:

```
bytes[0] = value & 0xff;
bytes[1] = (value >> 8) & 0xff;
bytes[2] = (value >> 16) & 0xff;
bytes[3] = (value >> 24) & 0xff;
```

That represents what I'm trying to do much more readably in my opinion than using the equivalent division operations.

Comment: For your example, I agree that arithmetic shifts are better than division. However, I think *logical* shifts (e.g. JavaScript's `>>>`) would be better still. Are there any situations where *arithmetic* shifts are the best solution?

Comment: @PaulBaker: I tend to think of `>>>` as more just a "non-sign-preserving" shift rather than "logical" vs "arithmetic". And if you're using a language which supports unsigned types, and you're shifting *those*, then there's no need for any distinction. Note that a language may support overloading the shift operators for logical bitsets as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. This is a legacy of the old C world, where these operators could be relied on to emit specific instructions. They imply low level control which simply should not be needed or expected. Unfortunately in many cases it still is, and C/C++ will be with us for a long time to come.

But I take issue with your proposed alternative. The proper implementation in my view would be a library function that encapsulated likely uses of bit shifting at a higher level, so that programmers were not obliged to explain to the computer how to do things computers are actually rather good at.

Possible functions might include

```
int Shift(int value, int distance);
unsigned int Shift(unsigned int value, int distance);
unsigned int Rotate(unsigned int value, int distance);
double DivideByPower(double value, double base, double power);
```

A smart compiler could easily optimise those into the best available instructions.